# What is the name of the dynamically generated elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am generating an interface dynamically but I don't know how to access to the attributes of these since I don't know what name they adopt.

I leave the example interface. I was thinking that maybe they adopt names like: `Textbox_1` `Textbox_2`.... But to be guessing, I preferred to ask.

I leave the example interface.

## Main file

```
    from UIMAIN import *
    
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MAIN):
        def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.setupUi(self)
    
            for x in range(3):
                self.Make()
    
        def Make(self):
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 177))
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
            
            self.TRAM = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.TRAM.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 141, 161))
            self.TRAM.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(141, 161))
            
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Verdana")
            font.setPointSize(9)
            
            self.TRAM.setFont(font)
            self.TRAM.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
            self.TRAM.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
            self.TRAM.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            self.TRAM.setObjectName("TRAM")
    
            self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.TRAM)
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
```

## UI file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MAIN.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MAIN(object):
    def setupUi(self, MAIN):
        MAIN.setObjectName("MAIN")
        MAIN.resize(371, 201)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MAIN)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.AREA = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.AREA.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 351, 181))
        self.AREA.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(351, 181))
        self.AREA.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);")
        self.AREA.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.AREA.setObjectName("AREA")
        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 349, 179))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.AREA.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        MAIN.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MAIN)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MAIN)

    def retranslateUi(self, MAIN):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MAIN.setWindowTitle(_translate("MAIN", "MainWindow"))
```

Comment: Well, you can easily see all the attributes in `Ui_MAIN`, which are what you entered in qt designer. And then you can see all the attributes you created yourself in `MainWindow`. What else do you need to know?

Comment: @ekhumoro You misunderstood, the OP refers to the objects that are created in his loop. If you downvote his question, please reconsider changing that.

Comment: @AlejandroCondori I didn't misunderstand and I didn't downvote. Name binding in pyqt doesn't work any differently to normal python. If you overwrite a variable or attribute, the object will no longer be accessible via that name (although it may still be accessible via other means). There's no magical name creation - the attributes you can see in the current code are all you're going to get, with or without the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the widgets created in `MainWindow.Main`, they are bound to whatever name you give them. Since you are overwriting the same attributes every time you call `Make`, the previously created widgets won't be bound to explicit attribute names. If you want easy access to the widgets after creating them you could put them in a container like a list, e.g.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MAIN):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
   
        self.scroll_area_widgets = []
        self.TRAM_widgets = []
        for x in range(3):
            self.Make()

    def Make(self):
        scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scroll_area_widgets.append(scrollAreaWidgetContents)
           
        TRAM = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.TRAM_widgets.append(TRAM)
         
        # rest of setup where self.TRAM is replaced with TRAM and 
        # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents with scrollAreaWidgetContents ....
```

This allows you to access the widgets created in `Make` via `self.TRAM_widgets[]` and `self.scroll_area_widgets[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store every object you create into a variable if you want to get access to them. I suggest creating a list, and each time you create an object store it as an element of that list. Later you can have access to the objects via the index of the lists.

Something like this:

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MAIN):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)0
        num = 3
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = [None for _ in range(num)]
        for x in range(num):
            self.Make(x)
    
    def Make(self, index):
       self.scrollAreaWidgetContents[index] = QtWidgets.QWidget()
       self.scrollAreaWidgetContents[index].setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 177))
       self.scrollAreaWidgetContents[index].setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
```

In the example above, I stored every `scrollAreaWidgetContents` that are created as elements of a list. Do that to all other objects that you create in your loop.